# Highlight numbers in a string using regex based on a condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like below

```
str = "a.b().to('cp_5_m').from('cp_150_m').in('tm', by(1586754175000,1589362375000)).for('fr')"
```

I want to replace numbers with a `<span>number</span>` where `number` is not inside any quotes. As you can see there is number in `'cp_5_m'` but that's inside a quote. However there are also numbers like `1586754175000,1589362375000` which are not inside any quotes.

Now I am not very familiar with `regex` but finding a number is easy by using a basic `regex` like `/[0-9]/g` but I want the numbers to be only found by the specified conditions and get replaced by a `span` containing those numbers.

So my final string should look something like this

```
str = "a.b().to('cp_5_m').from('cp_150_m').in('tm', by(<span>1586754175000</span>,<span>1589362375000</span>)).for('fr')"
```

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: `s.replace(/("[^"]*")|\d+/g, function(a,b) {return b ? b : "<span>" + a + "</span>";})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, your regex also puts span around `5` in `'cp_5_m'`. The regex should avoid numbers that are inside quotes.

Comment: Sorry, if you have only single quotes, use `s.replace(/('[^']*')|\d+/g, function(a,b) {return b ? b : "<span>" + a + "</span>";})`. I used double quotes above. BTW, what quotes do you want to support? Can there be any escaped sequences inside the quotes?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works now. I want to avoid numbers that are inside both double quotes and single quotes. So basically any number which is not inside any quotes (both single and double) should get highlighted. Do you think this regex can be modified further? I just realised this string may have both kind of quotes.

Comment: And can there be escaped quotes? `"abc\"123"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no there will not be any escaped quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and skip the substrings in between single/double quotation marks by matching them, and the numbers you need to wrap with tags can be matched and captured in any other contexts.

Use `.replace` method with a callback method:

```
str = str.replace(/"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|(\d+)/g, function(a,b) {return b ? "<span>" + b + "</span>" : a;});
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var str = "a.b().to(\"cp_5_m\").from('cp_150_m').in('tm', by(1586754175000,1589362375000)).for('fr')";
var rx = /"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|(\d+)/g;
console.log(str.replace(rx, function(a,b) {return b ? "<span>" + b + "</span>" : a;}));
```

Here,

- `"[^"]*"|'[^']*'` - matches `"`, then 0 or more chars other than `"`, and then a `"`, or a `'`, then 0+ chars other than `'` and then `'`
- `|` - or
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits.

If Group  1 matches, the match is wrapped with a tag, else, it is put back as is.

Comment: this is great! Thanks!